# GvrMainViewer black screen in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

I've added a terrain and dropped the GvrMainViewer in my scene. I haven't changed any settings at all. When I press the play button I see the VR overlay but both screens are black. [Both black screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGWwt.png)

I've tried adding a camera to the GvrMainViewer and it's working then when I press play. But when I then build it into an android app, the app just shows the camera perspective and nothing with VR.

Any idea how I can get the VR working in an app?

Comment: Have you tried opening the `GVRDemo` scene in the Examples folder? Does it work then?

Comment: Yes it's working there, do you have any idea why that scene does work?

Comment: Could be that you have changed something in the process of making your app. I suggest you grab everything from the demo scene and load it in your scene.

Comment: When I build the GVR demo for android, it also shows a normal screen and no vr interface on my phone in the app